# Continuous mapping not exist on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose that $\Delta\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is a closed triangle area, $\partial \Delta$ its boundary (namely the 3 sides of the triangle). I'd like to show that there doesn't exist a continuous mapping from $\Delta$ to $\partial \Delta$, which maps each side of $\partial \Delta$ to itself.

This problem may have something to do with Brouwer's fixed point theorem, but I have no idea now.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to fix $\partial\Delta$ (i.e. $f(x)=x$ for points in the boundary) then such a map does not exist by the [no retraction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#No-retraction_theorem) which is indeed a consequence of Brouwer's fixed point theorem, as $(\Delta,\partial \Delta) \simeq (\Bbb B^2,\Bbb S^1)$.

Comment: That's neat. I forgot to use the homotopy.

Comment: @S.James I use a homeomorphism of pairs, not an homotopy.

Answer (score 1):

As Henno points out, $(\Delta, \partial\Delta)$ and $(D^2, S^1)$ are homeomorphic as pairs. So, I'm going to attack your problem by replacing $(\Delta, \partial\Delta)$ with $(D^2, S^1)$.

Suppose that such a continuous map exists---call this map $r : D^2 \rightarrow S^1$. Then, we can define a [deformation retraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)) $R: D^2 \times [0, 1] \rightarrow S^1$ by the assignment:
\begin{equation} R(x, t) := tr(x) + (1-t)x 
\end{equation}
(You should check that

1. $\forall (x, t) \in D^2 \times [0,1]: \|R(x, t)\| \leq 1$
2. $\forall x \in D^2: R(x, 1) \in S^1 \land R(x, 0) = x$ and
3. $\forall a \in S^1: R(a, 1) = a$.)

However, deformation retractions are homotopy equivalences---they induce *isomorphisms* between fundamental groups! Likewise, $R$ induces the isomorphism
$R_* : \pi_1(D^2, -) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1, -)$. But this is a contradiction. Note that $\pi_1(D^2, -) \cong \{0\}$ and $\pi_1(S^1, -) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $R_*$ is the zero map, the *furthest* thing from a group isomorphism. It cannot be the case that $r$ exists, completing the proof.

(To be honest, I'm not sure how to apply Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem to answer your question. However, a method similar to the one that I've outlined above can be used to prove BFP. You can find an excellent explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djaSbHKK5yc).)